# playing a random short array in AudioTrack results nothing

Tags: java, android

I want to know how Audiotrack works, so I generated a random short array with length 60000, and tried to play it with AudioTrack:

```
public short[] generatedNoise=new short[60000];
for(int i=0;i<=59999;i++){
                generatedNoise[i]=(short) random.nextInt(Short.MAX_VALUE + 1);
            }
AudioTrack  at=new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 48000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 48000*7 /* 1 second buffer */,
                        AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                at.write(generatedNoise, 0, generatedNoise.length);
                at.play();
```

But the speaker outputs nothing, and there is no error message in my console. I tried using this method playing a wav file and it works perfect, can someone tell me the reason? My objective is to output some noise from the speaker.

Update: I just generated a short array like with the following code and still get not output:

```
          short[] wave=new short[100000];

          int i=0;
          while(i<=99997){
              wave[i]=32767;
              wave[i+1]=0;
              wave[i+2]=-32767;
              wave[i+3]=0;
              i=i+4;
          }
```

Comment: How long have you waited to see if something happens? 60,000 is a lot of iterations. Maybe you should add some log output after the loop completes, just to make sure that it's actually finished.

Comment: yes i did print out b4 playing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, for the buffer size I just changed it to the actual size of the array, and it works fine. Thank you for your concerns.

Comment: Hi, can I ask what you said "actual size of the array" is ?  Isn't your "generatedNoise.length" actual size ?

Comment: I think "buffer size" refers to the 5th parameter of the AudioTrack constructor. I did this and I still cannot get any sound to play.